# How to convert the sample rate with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/). I would like to change the sample rate of the audio file.

In ffmpeg-, it seems that you can change the sample rate as follows.

```
ffmpeg -i" movie.mp3 "-y" movie.flac "-ar 44100
```

`-ar` is sample rate.

How do I change the sample rate by ffmpeg-python?

This is my source code that is currently being written.

```
stream = ffmpeg.input(input_file_path)
audio = stream.audio
stream = ffmpeg.output(audio, output_file_path)
ffmpeg.run(stream, capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I soleved.

I can set keyword arguments like this.

```
stream = ffmpeg.output(audio, output_file_path, **{'ar': '16000','acodec':'flac'})
```

It is important to keep the `**` in place. If you remove it, you will get an error.